# Json schema validator, how to validate if key is not static

Tags: json, python-3.x, validation

I am trying to validate this specific schema:

```
{
    "messages": [
        {
        "name": "test msg",
        "id": "0x100",
        "signals": {
                    "0": {"name": "Engine RPM", "bit_length": 16},
                    "16": {"name": "Gear", "bit_length": 3},
                    "19": {"name": "Battery Voltage", "bit_length": 5}
                   }
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using the python `from jsonschema import Draft4Validator` to validate this schema... however I am not sure how to continue.

This is my current schema validation so far:

```
{
    "$schema" : "https://json-schema.org/schema#",
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : 
    {
        "messages" :
        {
            "type" : "array",
            "items" : 
            {
                "properties" : 
                {
                    "name" : 
                    {
                        "type" : "string"
                    },
                    "id" : 
                    {
                        "type" : "string"
                    },
                    "signals" : 
                    {
                        "type" : "object"
                    },

                    "properties" :
                    {


                    }
                },
                "required": ["name", "id", "signals"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is I am not sure how to deal with the objects that are in the "signals" key as they start with a string and are NOT consistent ("0", "16", "19")... How could I go about validating this by ensuring the type is always a string, disregarding whether or not the string is consistent.

Thanks to all of those who reply in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by doing the following:

```
{
    "$schema" : "https://json-schema.org/schema#",
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : 
    {
        "messages" :
        {
            "type" : "array",
            "items" : 
            {
                "properties" : 
                {
                    "name" : 
                    {
                        "type" : "string"
                    },
                    "id" : 
                    {
                        "type" : "string"
                    },
                    "signals" : 
                    {
                        "type" : "object"
                    },

                    "properties" :
                    {
                        "start_bit" : 
                        {
                            "type" : "object",
                            "properties" :
                            {
                                "name" :
                                {
                                    "type" : "string"
                                },
                                "bit_length" :
                                {
                                    "type" : "string"
                                },
                                "factor" : 
                                {
                                    "type" : "string"
                                },
                                "offset" : 
                                {
                                    "type" : "string"
                                }
                            },
                            "required" : ["name", "bit_length", "factor", "offset"]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "required": ["name", "id", "signals"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To "avoid" having to keep the string consistent, in the validator file, I can put any string (obviously it makes more sense to name the string what is represents, in my case "start_bit") and then by NOT having it be required.